# Open an external program from python and examine its memory

Tags: python, windows, memory, popen

I want to run an external program from python (using popen for example) and be able to look at its memory while it's running.

Cheatengine and other similar applications are able to do this but I want to do it from python because I want use the memory I'm reading in my python application.

One way to do it is to run gdb from python and interact with it but it's not a really clean method and has a lot of dependencies on Windows.

What's a nice and clean way to do this?

Thanks for your answers.